# android :error in updating data on my server

Tags: php, android

i am working in android. i have uploaded my database and APIs on my server.  when i call a get API. then it works fine. But when i call **POST API** like as **Registration** then it creates problem and does not respond.

this is the problem in my LogCat

Some possible problems are:

Missing or unknown request method.

Missing URL.

Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).

Request is too large.

Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.

Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.

HTTP/1.1 Expect: feature is being asked from an HTTP/1.0 software.

when use API and database which is stored on my localhost then everything works fine.. please help me to find out the reason of error... is this related to proxy or something else. yes i activated proxy on my server.

if you want to ask anything related to my question then i am 24 hours available here..

this is the error page. please visit this link...

**http://www.2shared.com/document/zTO7-*x*/error.html**

please see my problem.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I know your activity may be large but can you update your question with the related code (your HttpClient)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by my self experience... this problem is created just because of my server proxy setting.

I allow that application from my server proxy then it working fine...

Thank you all who tried to help me...